# Why did POCO chose to use Posix semaphores for OSX?

Tags: macos, posix, poco, semaphore

I am a new bee to MAC/OSX. I am working on Titanium a cross platform runtime, which uses POCO library for most of the portable C++ API. I see that POCO uses POSIX semaphore for its NamedMutex implementation on OSX as opposed to SysV semaphore that it is using for few other *NIX.

```
bool NamedMutexImpl::tryLockImpl()
{
#if defined(sun) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__osf__) || defined(__QNX__) || defined(_AIX)
 return sem_trywait(_sem) == 0;
#else
 struct sembuf op;
 op.sem_num = 0;
 op.sem_op  = -1;
 op.sem_flg = SEM_UNDO | IPC_NOWAIT;
 return semop(_semid, &op, 1) == 0;
#endif
}
```

For few searches, I see that SysV sem_* API is supported on OSX as well: http://www.osxfaq.com/man/2/semop.ws. Any Idea, why POCO developers chose to use POSIX API on OSX?

I am particularly intested in SEM_UNDO functionality in the above call, which the POSIX semaphores can't give.

Comment: I would venture to guess because OSX is rooted in BSD, which branched off from UNIX tree before SysV came to be, and therefore for OSX POSIX is probably "closer to native" than SysV.

Answer (score 1):

> Any Idea, why POCO developers chose to use POSIX API on OSX?

That seems to be rather arbitrary decision on part of POCO developers: both semaphores do not really match the Windows' named semaphores (after which they are apparently crafted). There is no semaphore on POSIX which has its own symbolic namespace akin to a file system. (SysV sems have namespace made of integer ids, but no symbolic names.)

If the posted code really comes from the library, I can only advise to stop relying on the library for portability. Well, at least with the semaphores you apparently have to start your own implementation already.

**Edit1**. Check how the semaphores are implemented for Windows. It's common for such libraries to use Windows' critical sections. Then the POSIX sem_t is a proper match. You need SEM_UNDO only if the semaphore is accessed by several processes - it doesn't work for threads. I.e. undo happens when the process crashes. Though the fact that on Linux they use SysV is quite troubling. SysV semaphores are global and thus have OS limit (can be changed on run-time) on their number - while sem_t semaphores are local to the process, are just a structure in private memory and are limited only by the amount of local memory process can allocate.

P.S. Reluctantly. Real reason might be that the POCO main development takes place on Windows (usual to the "portable libraries"; they are "portable to Windows" so to say trying to make *NIX look like Windows). UNIX implementation is very very often an afterthought, implemented by somebody who has seen terminal screen from few meters away and never read the man page further the function prototype. That was my personal experience with couple of such "portable libraries" in the past.

Comment: Yes, for the use case I have, I need semaphores to be accessible across processes and cleaned-up on exit (including crash)